# Travel Consent letter for child traveling with parent to Netherlands

Tags: schengen, children, netherlands

I am planning to visit Netherlands with my family (wife and a child who is less than 2 years old). One of the requirement for the visa is "original travel consent letter signed by both parents/legal guardians".

Can someone guide me that what should the letter contain? Is there a form I need to fill in?

Just to add, I am travelling from UK to Netherlands.

Comment: Where did you read that? I was under the impression that it only was a requirement if the child was traveling alone or with only one parent.

Comment: This is only the requirement if only one or none of you are traveling with the child or if one of you is not a parent of a child.

Comment: It says here and doesn't mentions if needs to be provided only when child is travelling with one parent or alone. http://nl.vfsglobal.co.uk/pdf/Tourist_Visa17012013.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some consulates do provide forms to fill in but here is a [template from the Swedish ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.swedenabroad.com/ImageVaultFiles/id_9995/cf_52/Consent.PDF). This should generally be fine for any country and since Sweden is also in the Schengen area the exact same rules apply than for the Netherlands.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no such mention in the [Netherlands VFS](http://nl.vfsglobal.co.uk/pdf/Tourist_Visa17012013.pdf) there is a specificity added in the [Consulate of Austria page](http://www.bmeia.gv.at/en/embassy/london/practical-advice/schengen-visa-residence-permits/schengen-visa-application-requirements.html):

> 5.1. Minors (children below 18 years):
>
> Birth certificate
>
> Minors travelling alone or with only one parent:
>
> Original passports of both parents (unless one parent has the sole custody or residence order for the child);
>
> Proof of consent of parental authority or legal guardian

and also from the [Netherlands Consular Services Page](http://www.rsonac.org/schengen-visa/visa-instructions-for-the-netherlands---schengen/other-citizens).  You can certainly confirm directly with the consulate but I still think you won't need it if both of you are traveling with the child.

Comment: Thanks, point 12 on Netherlands VFS does state that a consent letter is required, but as you said might only be required in case of child travelling alone or with one of the parent.

Comment: @Junaid There have been multiple occasions where points like this have come up because of "lost in translation", so this needs to be clarified directly with the consulate but normally the concern is that one parent takes the child out of a country without the consent of another.